# Flutter json map array of obejcts to class

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to map the following json structure to models. I try to map the array to an List and than parse each set to model.

The following error would be displayed:

type 'MappedListIterable' is not a subtype of type 'List'

---

Json

```
  {
      "objectId": "vbbZIPV6qs",
      "sets": [
        {
          "repetitions": 10,
          "weight": 10,
          "time": 0
        }
      ],
      "description": "",
      "type": "EXERCISE",
    }
```

---

Flutter

```
class PlanItem {
  String type;
  String description;
  List<Set> sets = [];

  PlanItem(this.type, this.description, this.sets);

  factory PlanItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PlanItem(
      json['type'],
      json['description'],
      (json['sets'] as List).map((i) {
        return Set.fromJson(i);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class Set {
  int repetitions;
  int weight;
  int time;

  Set(this.repetitions, this.weight, this.time);

  // convert Json to an exercise object
  factory Set.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Set(
      json['repetitions'] as int,
      json['weight'] as int,
      json['time'] as int,
    );
  }
}
```

---

Error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code `perfectly` works for me.

We will get this error if we miss `toList()` in below snippet,

```
(json['sets'] as List).map((i) {
    return Set.fromJson(i);
  }).toList(), // removing toList will get below error
// type 'MappedListIterable<Map<String, int>, Set>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Set>'
```

Comment: What version of flutter do you use? I use 0.5.1

Comment: Same as yours. Dart VM version: 1.24.3

Comment: Before this line `class Set {`, `}` is missing in above code (looks Set as inner class). As `Dart` doesn't allow inner class, it should be `typo`

Comment: Sorry, I will change code.  The model looks so . https://gist.github.com/aBuder/ca09a5d08ede710e032f26dbaf45560a